# Why does my derivation of $\mathcal{L(\frac{f(t)}{t})}$ lead to a wrong answer?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to prove that

$$\mathcal{L(\frac{f(t)}{t})(s)} = \int_s^{\infty}\mathcal{L(f(t))}(u)du$$

Here's my attempt:

$$\mathcal{L(\frac{f(t)}{t})}(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f(t)}{t}e^{-st}dt$$

By using Leibnitz' differentiation under the integral sign, we get:

$$ \dfrac{d\mathcal{L(\frac{f(t)}{t})}(s)}{ds}=-\int_{0}^{\infty} f(t)e^{-st}dt=-\mathcal{L(f(t))(s)}$$

$$\mathcal{L(\dfrac{f(t)}{t})}(s)= - \int \mathcal{L(f(t))(s)} ds$$

It can be rewritten as:

$$\mathcal{L(\dfrac{f(t)}{t})}(s)= - \int_{0}^{s} \mathcal{L(f(t))(u)} du$$

But this is apparently wrong. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong on my own.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you insert your integration limits in a wrong way? Why are you taking the one limit as $0$ instead of $\infty$? Take your intermediate result

$$ \frac{d}{du}\mathcal{L(f(t)/t)}(u)=-\mathcal{L(f(t))(u)}$$

then integrate from $k\to\infty$ to $s$ to get
$$
\mathcal{L(f(t)/t)}(s)-\lim_{k\to\infty}\mathcal{L(f(t)/t)}(k) = \int_s^\infty\mathcal{L(f(t))(u)}du
$$
Finally you have to show that
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\mathcal{L(f(t)/t)}(k) = \lim_{k\to\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f(t)}{t}e^{-kt}dt \overset{?}{=} 0
$$
Now under certain conditions (which I don't remember, but which probably are fulfilled here) you can interchange the limit and the integration and note that "$e^{-\infty}=0$" to get the result

Comment: Why would you integrate from $\infty$ to $s$? That operation doesn't kill $\dfrac{d}{du}$.

Comment: What do you mean? I'm using $\int_a^b\frac{df(x)}{dx}dx = f(b)-f(a)$.

Comment: I take the equation that you're mentioning and do $\int_\infty^s\dots du$ on both sides.

Comment: The first one in my answer and the one in your previous comment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15976/discussion-between-stan-and-math-n00b).

Answer (score 1):

This is frequency integration.

Hint: RHS  = $\int_{s}^{\infty} F(u) du$ = $\int_{s}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} f(t)e^{-ut} dt du$

If you give up:

http://www.eee.hku.hk/~u3500898/LTProperty.pdf

I think the justification for the double integral swap is the same as the justification for your swapping of derivative and integral in your attempt.

Comment: This is a valid proof and I'd do it exactly the same way if I prove it from RHS to LHS, but I'm not looking for a valid proof now because it's an easy problem. I'm trying to understand why my method gives me a wrong result because I don't understand why my method is wrong and that makes me feel bad :P

Comment: @math.n00b Why is yours wrong? Just write the integrand as the integral of something and you get a double integral as in the link. I think.

Answer (score 0):

The hitch is at the end :

$\mathcal{L(\dfrac{f(t)}{t})}(s)= - \int \mathcal{L(f(t))(s)} ds$ + constant

It can be rewritten as:

$\mathcal{L(\dfrac{f(t)}{t})}(s)= - \int_{0}^{s} \mathcal{L(f(t))(u)} du +C$

Now, you will have to determine $C$ as

$C=  \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathcal{L(f(t))(u)} du $

Comment: Isn't $C$ equal to $$\int_o^{\infty} \dfrac{f(t)}{t} dt$$? (plug $s=0$ into your last equation)